# .net core 2 Entity Framework - ApplicationUser Extended Foreign Key object not populating on get

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-2.0

I've extended the ApplicationUser to include a OrganizationId and a Organization object that is supposed to map to a foreign Organization table. This works fine on initial user registration - if it is an existing Organization, I just populate the OrganizationId field. If it is a new Organization, I instantiate a new Organization object and a new Organization gets created in the Organization table.

When I pull the record down with GetUserAsync, the correct CityId and OrganizationId fields are pulled. The UserCity and Organization objects are NULL though. I know I can do a manual lookup to query for a City/Organization based on the IDs returning, but I was wondering if Entity Framework has a mechanism to populate these two objects with the foreign keyed counterparts automatically on GetUserAsync.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public int? CityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual City UserCity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public bool AddToConstantContact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to populate foriegn key object? if so can you please share your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Fetching Records you need to use include keyword to get the referenced values. Ex

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
    .ToList();
}
```

For Your code Will be something like

```
context.Include("Organization").Include("City")
```

Its also not loaded automatically in entity framework core because lazy loading is not supported yet till version 2.1.

For more Info check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data